# C# Copy Array by Value

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a typed array `MyType[] types;`
and i want to make and independant copy of this array. i tried this

```
MyType[] types2 = new MyType[types.Length] ;

types2 = types ;
```

but this create a reference to the first. I then tried

```
Array.Copy( types , types2 , types.Length ) ;
```

but I have the same problem: changing a value in the first array changes the value in the copy as well.

How can I make a completely independent or deep copy of an Array, IList or IEnumerable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implement a clone method on MyType, using protected method MemberwiseClone (performs shallow copy) or using a deep cloning technique. You can have it implement an ICloneable then write several extensions methods that will clone the corresponsing collection.

```
interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static T[] Clone<T>(this T[] array) where T : ICloneable<T>
    {
        var newArray = new T[array.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            newArray[i] = array[i].Clone();
        return newArray;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> Clone<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) where T : ICloneable<T>
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            yield return item.Clone();
    }
}
```

You must do this because while a new array is created when you use Array.Copy it copies the references, not the objects referenced. Each type is responsible for copying itself.

Comment: Microsoft says: [we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) because it doesn't specify deep vs shallow copy semantics. Better create an own IDeepCopyable interface.

Answer (score 19):

Based on the first post, all he needs is this for "an independent copy of the array". Changes to the `shallowCopy` array itself would not appear in the `types` array (meaning element assignment, which really is what he showed above despite saying "deep copy"). If this suits your needs, it will have the best performance.

```
MyType[] shallowCopy = (MyType[])types.Clone();
```

He also mentions a "deep copy" which would be different for mutable types that are not recursive value-type aggregates of primitives. If the `MyType` implements `ICloneable`, this works great for a deep copy:

```
MyType[] deepCopy = (MyType[])Array.ConvertAll(element => (MyType)element.Clone());
```

Answer (score 14):

For the impatient:

```
newarray = new List<T>(oldarray).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you first create a list and then calling `.ToArray()` instead of `oldarray.ToArray()`? Your method will call `CopyTo` in the List constructor and `Copy` in `ToArray`, I'm not sure I see the point

Answer (score 7):

If your type is serializable you can use serialization techniques to get a copy of your array (including deep copies of the items):

```
private static object GetCopy(object input)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, input);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
MyType[] items = new MyType[2];
// populate the items in the array

MyType[] copies = (MyType[])GetCopy(items);
```

Comment: my type is not serializable =(

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing: make a copy of an array by value for things like sorting so that I could later reinitialize another temp array with the original source array.  After researching this, I found this cannot be done so simply.  So, I made a workaround.  I will use my own code below:

```
string[] planetNames = new string[] { "earth", "venus", "mars" };

string[] tempNames = new string[planetNames.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < planetNames.Length; i++)
{
     tempNames[i] = planetNames[i];
}
```

*planetNames* is my source array.  *tempNames* is the array which I will later sort independently of planetNames.  I have tested this and this code does not sort *planetNames* when I sort *tempNames* which is what I was attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a copy of just an array with references to objects in old array (or if you have array of value type objects), simplest solution is

```
var newArray = oldArray.ToArray()
```

If you want deep copy you should have a method which copies single object of your type (e.g. `public MyType Copy(MyType obj)`). Then solution will look like

```
var newArray = oldArray.Select(x => Copy(x)).ToArray()
```

Comment: To clarify, `Copy(x)` is a custom implementation, right?

Comment: Yes, there is no method to perform deep copy of object of any type. There is [MemberwiseClone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx) method in any object but it is protected and creates only shallow copy (copy of object itself but doesn't create new copies of fields of reference type), not deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

I've found if you just want a simple char array copy you can trick C# into doing a copy by value using the char:

```
char[] newchararray = new char[desiredchararray.Length];

for (int k = 0; k < desiredchararray.Length; k++)
{

   char thecharacter = newchararray[k];
   newchararray[k] = thecharacter;
   oldchararray[k] = oldchararray[k] + 1;

}
```

Seems to work for me but if anyone disagrees please let me know :)

Comment: char is a value type.  This will work different for reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the value of the array in this case are numbers

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] copyArr = new int[arr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i <arr.Length; i++)
{
    copyArr[i]=arr[arr.Length-i-1];
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",arr));**
```